# Register multiple tasks with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm building a simple helper class for sending emails in Django and Celery.

> My code

```
import logging

from celery import Task
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from render_block import render_block_to_string

from optilimo.celery import app
from reservations.models import Reservation

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Mailer(Task):
    """
    Build emails from template and send them via Celery.
    Includes some helper functions as well.
    """
    template = None
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    name = 'mailer'
    max_retries = 3

    def build_context(self, ctx):
        return ctx

    def run(self, to_email, ctx, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = self.build_context(ctx)

        subject = render_block_to_string(self.template, 'subject', ctx)
        plain = render_block_to_string(self.template, 'plain', ctx)
        html = render_block_to_string(self.template, 'html', ctx)

        send_mail(subject, plain, self.from_email,
                  [to_email], html_message=html)
        logger.info('Email sent to {}'.format(to_email))

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        super(Mailer, self).on_success(retval, task_id, args, kwargs)
        logger.info('Email with task ID {} was successfuly sent.'.format(task_id))

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        super(Mailer, self).on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)
        logger.error('Email with task ID {} was failed to send.'.format(task_id))
        logger.error('Error: {}'.format(str(exc)))


class QuoteRequestMailer(Mailer):
    template = 'mails/internal/quote_request.html'


class ReservationDetailsMailer(Mailer):
    template = 'mails/internal/reservation_details.html'

    def build_context(self, ctx):
        reservation = Reservation.objects.first()
        return {'reservation': reservation}


app.tasks.register(QuoteRequestMailer)
app.tasks.register(ReservationDetailsMailer)
```

> Problem

When I register more than one task (for example in the code above), the last task registered get's called no matter what class I call.

For example, if I do:

```
mail = QuoteRequestMailer()
mail.delay(to_email='demo@mail.com', ctx={'data':'Test'})
```

The worker would execute the `ReservationDetailsMailer` task and not the `QuoteRequestMailer` one. How can I register multiple tasks this way?

Comment: You are a lifesaver!! I spent 2 days looking for a solution such as this! I have to define a tasks dynamically. So thank you sir, I salute you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding a `name` attribute to the child classes.

> Example

```
class QuoteRequestMailer(Mailer):
    name='mailer.quote_request'  # Important
    template = 'mails/internal/quote_request.html'
```